Improve valid pairs algorithm time complexity
I was solving a task:
Input n,m,k - integer numbers and integer array arr of size n
The pair of elements in arr is valid if two conditions are true

std::abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) <= m
arr[i] + arr[j] <= k

Output - number of valid pairs
Example:
Input
4 1 5
1 3 2 3

Output
3

The output is 3, because of pairs (1,2) (3, 2) and (2, 3)
My code is working. But it's time complexity is O(N^2) and I have a TIME LIMIT error
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, m, k;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    sort(begin(arr), end(arr));

    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] <= k and abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) <= m) {
                res++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}

I think that I should apply idea of sorting, how to reduce time complexity of my code? I guess it should be O(N*logN)

A common technique is to maintain a window into a sorted array. Say you start with a window of size 1 starting and ending at arr[0]. Then you grow a window by moving the upper boundary to the right or shrink it by moving the lower boundary to the right.

@n.m.couldbeanAI could you please elaborate?
For test 1 2 3 4 5 and limit k=6  Pair (1,5) is valid, but (3,4) is not valid, how can I maintain window?

Suppose you fix index j and find i1<=i2<j such that all these and only these pairs (i,j) with i1<=i<=i2 are good. You increment j. How should i1 and i2 change?

@n.m.couldbeanAI if i1 + newJ don't satisfy conditions, then I should increase i1 until i1 and newJ satisfy conditions

You can use binary search to find the range of valid numbers less than the current element that can be matched to create a pair. The absolute value can be removed in this way since the current element will always be the larger element in the pair.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
int main() {
    int n, m, k;
    std::cin >> n >> m >> k;
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    for (int& x : vec) std::cin >> x;
    std::ranges::sort(vec);
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        auto left = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + i, vec[i] - m), 
            right = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + i, k - vec[i]);
        res += left < right ? right - left : 0;
    }
    std::cout << res;
    return 0;
}


You could sort your collection via quicksort as the first step, that's a complexity of O(NlogN).
Now that the set is sorted, if you want to find a number's pairs, you can apply binary search, finding the boundaries, which has a complexity of O(logN) for each number and of course having N numbers, this adds up to O(NlogN), so you will end up having 2 * O(NlogN), which is essentially O(NlogN).

You are correct, your current implementation has a time complexity of O(N²) due to the nested loops which is not optimal. You O(NlogN) by sorting the array in ascending order and using a two pointer approach to count the two value pairs efficiently. This will eliminate the need for the nested for loops.
